# reorganize sheet to delete duplicated data check if colA has value on Col2

Tags: excel

First of all sorry for the subject, I'll explain my issue here.

I have a very long data on MSExcel of user **Privilege Name** and **Privilege Features** (more than 2000 rows)

Some of these Privileges has same features but with different name, in fact the company did not setup an structure of these privileges with a correct name that represent a user role

This an example of the data that I took from the company:

[image]

Where you can find that the **Privilege Name** and **Privilege Features** duplicated till it displays all **Privilege Sub Features** 
To simplify the **Privilege Sub Features** I've concatenate **Privilege Features** with **Privilege Sub Features**.

for example:

- **Admin**  Privilege  has **all** **Sub Features**
- **sales** Admin Has Only All **Sales sub Features**
- **Sales** User has Only **Salese.Sub1** **Sub Features**

I want to reorganize the data sheet to display a table of

- Privilege name only once in row
- Privilege Sub Features in column
- if Privilege name has Privilege Sub Features then type 1 else 0

The final datasheet will look like this:

[image]

how can do that for the datasheet of 2000 row ?

Comment: Try using a pivot table. That should do the trick.

Comment: Exactly what I need and more,  thank you.